# programatically create EditText fields in fragment from a seekbar

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-fragments, seekbar

EDIT: Here is the new code you suggested:

```
package com.mwerner.mycalc.finance;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class F_NPV extends Fragment {

    EditText[] DynamicField = new EditText[16];

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.npv, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    final LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.npv_calcfields);
    EditText editText = new EditText(getActivity());
    final int i = 0;
    editText.setId(i); //Set id so that you can remove that EditText in the future.
    editText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    linearLayout.addView(editText);
    SeekBar bar = (SeekBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.npv_seekbar);
    final TextView selection = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.npv_selected);

    bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekbar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            // to display to the user how many he has selcted
            selection.setText("You chose " + progress + "periods");
            if ( i > progress) {
                i--;
                EditText editText = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(i);
                linearLayout.removeView(editText);
            }

            else {
                EditText editText = new EditText(getActivity());
                editText.setId(i);
                editText.setHint("EditText No: " + (i+1));
                editText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                linearLayout.addView(editText);
                i++;
            }
        }
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekbar) {}
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {}
    });
}
}
```

EDIT 2:

I fixed the "lag" in reducing the number of fields when I slide down fast.

```
bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekbar, int progress,
        boolean fromUser) {
         // to display to the user how many he has selcted

        selection.setText("You chose " + progress + "periods");
        if ( i > progress) {
            while (i > progress) {
                i--;
                EditText editText = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(i);
                linearLayout.removeView(editText);  
            }
        }

        else {
            while (i < progress) {
                EditText editText = new EditText(getActivity());
                editText.setId(i);
                editText.setHint("EditText No: " + (i+1));
                editText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                linearLayout.addView(editText);
                i++;    
            }
        }
    }
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekbar) {}
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {}
});
```

Now i need to do the same math operation with each field:

```
answer = entry / (Math.pow(1+r , i)
```

basically each entry gets divided by `(1+r)` to the power of the id that that field has... so the first text edit gets divided by `(1+r)^0`, the second field divided by `(1+r)^1` and so on..  how do i do that?

Edit 3:

```
calc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Double r1 = Double.parseDouble(r.getText().toString());
        EditText editText = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(i);
        TextView answer = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.npv_answer);
        double[] CashFlows;
        CashFlows = new double[i];
        double result = 0;
        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < i; i1++) {
            CashFlows[i] = (Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString()))/(Math.pow(1+r1, i));

        }

        for(double d : CashFlows) {
            result += d;
        }

        answer.setText("answer is " + result);
        }
    });
```

Basically this was my thought process. Please tell me where i went horribly wrong as this causes a crash when the `fragment` is loaded.

My idea was

Double r1 is used in the math
`TextView answer` is used to output the final answer

`EditText editText` is what you told me i need to reference it

Now i figured i'd put all the values the user enteres into the given fields into an array and also do the simple math to all of them. That is what the first for loop is for. Then i when that array is done, i figured i would add them all together since that is what i want. I found the code for a "For each" loop here

http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/flow/loops/foreach.html

Then when it is all summed up it should be one double in the variable result... then i'd simply set the text to that number...

Where did i go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create 2 layouts in your xml file for example 2 linear layouts or whatever you want.

In the first layout add the Seekbar alone.

Get the second layout by id from your Java code and add/remove a TextView programmatically to your second layout every time the progress changes.

This can be done as follows:

First get the second layout like this

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.npv_calcfields);
```

Second add your EditText:

```
EditText editText = new EditText(this);
editText.setId(i); //Set id so that you can remove that EditText in the future.
editText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
linearLayout.addView(editText);
```

**Edit:** This following is a working example:

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
        boolean fromUser) {
    if ( i > progress) {
        i--;
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(i);
        linearLayout.removeView(editText);
    }
    else {
        EditText editText = new EditText(SeekBarActivity.this);
        editText.setId(i);
        editText.setHint("EditText No: " + (i+1));
        editText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        linearLayout.addView(editText);
        i++;
    }
}
```

I hope I helped you. ;)

Comment: a little code for the adding would have helped but I can figure that one out on my own with the developer docs :) Thanks, this solution seems really intuitive and good :)

Comment: ok i can't figure it out, please help, i updated it as seen above and also the padding and stuff doesn't work either

Comment: @Killerpixler Sorry for my late reply :) I updated my answer with some code for you.

Comment: thanks for the proper way of a dressing the layout issues. But how do I remove the views again when I slide down? And how do I do the same bit of math to each value entered into each edittext?

Comment: @Killerpixler You've already set an id for each view, using as an example an incremental variable that increments with the SeekBar. When the user slide down all you have to do is to remove that set of EditText ids from the layout.

Comment: yes i understand that, but how to implent it? because as i see it, there is only one programatical way that tracks changes (onProgressChanged) and when I tried to put it somewere else i was unable to reference the variable that tells me what the user set it to.

Comment: @Killerpixler You can compare the oldProgress with progress. If progress is greater add more editText else remove editText till progress == oldProgress

Comment: Do i need to do this outside the OnProgressChanged? If so, how do I reference the progress variable that is inside that onProgressChanged method?

Comment: I just cant get it to work... how would i do that? I just cant find a way to add/remove the difference between where the seekbar is and how many edit texts are in existence... Can you write up more detailed code please?

Comment: Thanks, I updated the code but get a compile error. Please advise

Comment: @Killerpixler remove final from line: final int i = 0;

Comment: when i do that i get the error "Cannot refer to a non-final variable i inside an inner class defined in a different method" at the same 2 sections AND in the if statement if( i ...)

Comment: nevermind i just put the final int I line outside any method, it is now just in the class itself

Comment: it works now (i.e. it adds and takes views away) but when i move the slider quickly back and forth it sometimes doesn't remove all of them again and i have two editfields that have the text "EditText No: 1" in them

Comment: i fixed the lag. I amended the question to show it and the 2nd part that i was asking about how to reference the fields for math? I am sooooo very grateful for your help btw

Comment: @Killerpixler Not at all ;). You will reference the fields the same way you referenced them when you wanted to remove extra EditText  EditText editText = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(i); Then do your math.

Comment: I tried doing math to it but failed, i explained my chain of thought up in the question, please advise :)

Answer (score 0):

just create one `LinearLayout` in xml..like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/family_detail_linear"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        ></LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/family_detail_addbutton"
        android:text="Add More"
        />

</LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and find that `LinearLayout` in your `fragment`

```
public class MyFrag extends Fragment{


    private Button addmoremember;
    private Activity activity;
    private LinearLayout layout;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.family_details, container, false);

        activity=getActivity();
        addmoremember=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.family_detail_addbutton);
        layout=(LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.family_detail_linear);
       addmoremember.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                EditText edttexname= new EditText(activity);
                edttexname.setHint("Enter Name");

                layout.addView(edttexname);

            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```